# Client-side page load time analytics for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

Is there any **free** solution for Client-side page load time analytics on SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Apart from the developer dashboard?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to google analytics.
I need history of page load times.